# Nearest Neighbor and majority of a list in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm trying to define a procedure knn that takes a positive integer k, the coordinates of a house, a distance function, and the training data, and returns a list of the (at most) k nearest neighbors to the given house in the training data. The returned list should be in non-decreasing order by proximity to the given house.

Training data is given by:

```
(define training-data
   '((d (1 8)) (d (2 9)) (d (8 10)) (d (4 2)) (r (1 3)) (r (2 1)) (r (4 8)) (r (6 4))
      (d (7 3)) (r (1 5)) (d (1 9)) (d (6 2)) (r (10 9)) (d (7 7))
      (d (5 11)) (r (1 1)) (r (0 9)) (r (12 12)) (r (20 30))))
```

The distance function I'm using is taxicab-distance that takes two points and returns the sum of the absolute differences of their coordinates. Which is given by:

```
(define (taxicab-distance ls1 ls2)
   (+ (abs (- (car ls1) (cadr ls1))) (abs(- (car ls2) (cadr ls2)))))
```

An example of what I'm trying to do would be:

~(knn 3 '(3 8) taxicab-distance training-data)

-> ((r (4 8)) (d (1 8)) (d (2 9)))

So I know it will start off as:

```
(define (knn k point distance data)
```

I know I will have to take the distance of each point so do the caadr of the training-data and then repeat on the cdr of the list to get each value, but then how to compare it to the original value and then return the whole nested list is where I get lost.

Lastly, with this I also want to define a function called majority  that takes a non-empty list of labeled data and a non-empty list of labels, and returns the label that occurs most frequently. If there is more than one such label, then it doesn't matter which one your program returns.

With majority it'll take two arguments, a data set, and a list of what it's looking for. I know for training-data, it'll have to look at the caar of the data and do the same for the cdr and then count each d and r.

Answer (score 0):

```
(import (rnrs)
        (rnrs sorting)
        (only (srfi :1) take))

(define (knn k point distance data)
  ;; Is p1 is closer to point than p2?
  (define (data-distance-point< p1 p2)
    (< (distance point (cadr p1))
       (distance point (cadr p2))))

  ;; take k elements of the coordinates 
  ;; with the shortest path to point   
  (take (list-sort data-distance-point< data) k))

(knn 3 '(3 8) point-distance training-data) ; ==> ((r (4 8)) (d (2 9)) (d (1 8)))
```

I didn't use your distance function since (0,0)->(0,10) has shorter distance than (0,5)->(0,10) which doesn't make any sense. My result is what you get if you use Pythagoras to get the distance.

The fact that `point` has a different structure than the elements of `data` is strange. I would have preferred not having `cadr` in `data-distance-point<`.